# TabLayout in BottomNavigationView hides data, but after two swipes (in TabLayout) data appear

Tags: java, android

I created an activity with BottomNavigationView at the bottom. The second tab of bottomnavigationview consists TabLayout (of days of the week). 
But there is some strange mistake. When I run app, it's okay, then i got to the second tab with tablayout, it's okay, than i go back to the first tab (forth pic - it's like it should to be), it's okay, and then i go to the second tab again and it's empty. But if i make to swipes (for the next and next day in TabLayout), the data of that day will apear. And it's doesn't matter which tab in TabLayout was opened, you always should do two swipes (for back or next) to this tab appear
For example, i was at the 2nd tab. i swipe for 3(it's empty now), i swipe for 4(it's already not empty). then back to the 3(empty), back to the 2(not empty). So if i want 3 to appear, i should swipe to 5 or to 1. What I've done wrong?

This is how I add bottomNavigationView in ***activity_main.xml***

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />
```

This is ***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Fragment f1;
private Fragment f2;
private Fragment f3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f1 = new NotificationsFragment();
    f2 = new SheduleFragment();
    ((SheduleFragment) f2).setGroups(groups);  // it's the second panel with TabLayout
    f3 = new CabinetsFragment();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f1).commit();

}


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_notifications: {
                selectedFragment = f1;
                break;
            }
            case R.id.navigation_shedule:
                selectedFragment = f2;
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_cabinets:
                selectedFragment = f3;
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
        return true;
    }
};
```

}

Here is the fragment with TabLayout, that is gonna be in the second tab in BottomNavigationView

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLL">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Function onCreateView in Fragment (the tabs in TabLayout are)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_layout, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_days_view);

    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    ra = new DayRecycleAdapter(teachers,subjects, cabinets,timeBegs, timeEnds  );
    rv.setAdapter(ra);

    return view;
}
```

The fragment of the second tab in Bottom Navigation View

```
public class SheduleFragment extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private Group[] groups;
ViewPagerAdapter vpa;

DayFragment df1;
DayFragment df2;
DayFragment df3;
DayFragment df4;
DayFragment df5;
DayFragment df6;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shedule, container, false);

    df1 = new DayFragment();
    df2 = new DayFragment();
    df3 = new DayFragment();
    df4 = new DayFragment();
    df5 = new DayFragment();
    df6 = new DayFragment();

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    setNewFragments(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6);

    viewPager.setAdapter(vpa);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}


public void setGroups(Group[] groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}

public void setNewFragments(DayFragment df1, DayFragment df2, DayFragment df3, DayFragment df4, DayFragment df5, DayFragment df6) {

    vpa = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
    setInfo(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6);

    vpa.addFragment(df1, "пн");
    vpa.addFragment(df2, "вт");
    vpa.addFragment(df3, "ср");
    vpa.addFragment(df4, "чт");
    vpa.addFragment(df5, "пт");
    vpa.addFragment(df6, "сб");
}

public void changeFragments(DayFragment df1, DayFragment df2, DayFragment df3, DayFragment df4, DayFragment df5, DayFragment df6) {

    setOneDayInfo(df1, 0);
    setOneDayInfo(df2, 1);
    setOneDayInfo(df3, 2);
    setOneDayInfo(df4, 3);
    setOneDayInfo(df5, 4);
    setOneDayInfo(df6, 5);
}

public void setInfo(DayFragment df1, DayFragment df2, DayFragment df3, DayFragment df4, DayFragment df5, DayFragment df6) {

    setOneDayInfo(df1, 0);
    setOneDayInfo(df2, 1);
    setOneDayInfo(df3, 2);
    setOneDayInfo(df4, 3);
    setOneDayInfo(df5, 4);
    setOneDayInfo(df6, 5);
}

public void setOneDayInfo(DayFragment df, int i) {

    ArrayList<Lesson> lessons = groups[groupNumber-1].getDays()[i].getLessons();
    int n = lessons.size();

    String[] teachers = new String[n];
    String[] subjects = new String[n];
    String[] cabinets = new String[n];
    String[] timeBegs = new String[n];
    String[] timeEnds = new String[n];

    int j=0;

    for (Lesson les: lessons) {
        teachers[j] = les.teachersToString();
        subjects[j] = les.subjectsToString();
        cabinets[j]= les.cabinetsToString();
        timeBegs[j] = les.timeBegToSting();
        timeEnds[j] = les.timeEndToSting();
        ++j;
    }

    df.setTeachers(teachers);
    df.setSubjects(subjects);
    df.setCabinets(cabinets);
    df.setTimeBegs(timeBegs);
    df.setTimeEnds(timeEnds);

}

}
```

***ViewPagerAdapter:***

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragmentList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentListTitles.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentListTitles.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentListTitles.add(title);
}

}
```

Comment: can you show screen shot where do you get problem?

Comment: [link](https://pp.userapi.com/c855636/v855636600/31f78/uykfym091sg.jpg)